# Array Insert and Update error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a code which can insert an array of a tables and also update it.
But the problem is..

1. the insert works, but **only one record inserted, not all**
2. the update **not worked due an error "Undefined variable: Input, Key, Id_siswa** and **Missing argument 3 for Guru_m::editAbsen(**

Here's my code on Controller :

```
public function saveAbsensi()
{
 if ($this->input->post('kirimabsen')) {
 $input = $this->input->post();
 $id_mapel = $input['id_mapel'];
 $id_kelas = $input['id_kelas'];
 $index = 0;
 foreach ($input['id_siswa'] as $key => $val) {
  $data = [
    'id_siswa' => $input['id_siswa'][$key],
    'id_mapel' => $input['id_mapel'],
    'id_kelas' => $input['id_kelas'],
    'time_in' => time(),
    'tanggal' => date("d"),
    'bulan' => date("m"),
    // 'bulan' => '10',
    'tahun' => date("Y"),
    'keterangan' => $input['keterangan'][$key]
  ];
  $this->guru_m->saveAbsen($data);
 redirect('gr/absensi');
 }

 } elseif ($this->input->post('ubahabsen')) {
     $data = [
    'id_siswa' => $input['id_siswa'][$key],
    'id_mapel' => $input['id_mapel'],
    'id_kelas' => $input['id_kelas'],
    'time_in' => time(),
    'tanggal' => date("d"),
    'bulan' => date("m"),
    // 'bulan' => '10',
    'tahun' => date("Y"),
    'keterangan' => $input['keterangan'][$key]
  ];
    $this->guru_m->editAbsen($data);
 redirect('gr/absensi');
}
}
```

On model :

```
public function saveAbsen($data)
{
 return $this->db->insert('absensi', $data);
}

 public function editAbsen($data, $keterangan, $id_siswa)
 {
 $q = $this->db->set('keterangan', $data['keterangan']);
 $q = $this->db->where('id_siswa', $id_siswa['']);
 $q = $this->db->update('absensi', $data);
 $results = $this->db->affected_rows();
 return $results;
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong on that code?

Comment: You don't need `$this->db->set('keterangan', $data['keterangan'])` if you are passing `$data` into `update()`.  In fact, the `update()` method will happily receive an associative array as its 3rd parameter to represent the `WHERE` clause rules. `$this->guru_m->editAbsen($data)` is passing a single argument to the model method, but your `editAbsen()` method signature expects 3 arguments.

Comment: In your given code you are also doing ```redirect('gr/absensi');``` in foreach loop rather than ```if()``` ... it will get executed in  first loop..... i think this could also be an error...

Comment: Maybe you'd like to change your model method to this? https://3v4l.org/HboWo

Comment: It worked.. thank you mickmackusa.. i follow your steps!